# document.getElementById("myId").InnerHTML can't find <div id="myId">

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've having this problem with some JavaScript code.  I've simplified it in the error below because I've been able to pinpoint the problem by debugging.

HTML:

```
<select id="city_list_select" name="city">
    <div id="clist">
        <option>Select a Region First</option>
    </div>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("clist").innerHTML = "<option>Test</option>";
```

I'm getting this error returned:  TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.
So it seems as if JavaScript can't find that div there.  I was able to work around the problem by removing the div and changing the JS to getElementById("city_list_select"), but I would still like to figure out why the div isn't working in case I come across a similar problem in the future.

Comment: When / where is that JavaScript statement getting executed? It's possible that your element doesn't exist in the DOM yet when your JavaScript is getting executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... I don't think you can have a DIV tag inside a SELECT tag.  Try using the OPTION tag, or as you found out, replace all the OPTION tags using the SELECT tag's innerHTML.

```
<select id="city_list_select" name="city">            
  <option id="option1">Select a Region First</option>     
</select>
```

And don't forget that you can also use methods like `appendChild` to append new elements to existing ones.

Comment: The browser won't just remove the div though (I believe). It would rearrange the elements so that they are valid.

Comment: @FelixKling - possibly... I've never had the need to add a DIV to a SELECT tag so far, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: @FelixKling—perhaps, the important thing is that if a browser is given invalid HTML, the result is implementation dependent and may well differ from browser to browser. The result of invalid XML should be entirely consistent though. :-)

Comment: @RobG: True... I was just thinking, while this is a valid point, it might be more likely that the OP is executing the code before this part of the DOM is available. Anyways, it seemed the problem is solved so all is fine :)